Pulling objects from planet's surface by gravity
There is an episode of a TV show I will not name, in which objects from a planet's surface are being pulled into space by a (more or less sudden) high gravitational field. This struck me as ridiculous, because objects of different mass are still accelerated the same way in the same gravitational field.
Then I remembered that there is a way out, namely when the gravitational field on the other side of the planet is significantly smaller. The extreme example of this is spaghettification in proximity to a small black hole. So when there is an extreme environment that causes an extreme outcome, maybe there is a less-extreme environment that causes a less-extreme outcome, like pulling objects away from a planet's surface.
Is this in any way realistic?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When two massive bodies are adjacent to each other, then the gravitational acceleration felt by objects will be position dependent. For example, the contribution of the Moon to the acceleration of something at the surface of the Earth closest to the Moon is not the same as its contribution to acceleration at the centre of the Earth, because those two points are at different separations from the Moon.
This differential acceleration is responsible for tides and is known as a tidal acceleration.
The tidal acceleration depends roughly on $r^{-3}$ and so if you bring bodies closer together it becomes possible that the tidal acceleration exceeds the self-gravity at the centre of one of the objects. This is known as the Roche limit. At that point, objects could indeed be pulled off the surface and the body start to disintegrate.
If the Moon were to orbit only a few thousand km above the Earth's surface (a detailed calculation would have to include deformation of the Earth and Moon) then objects could be pulled off the Moon's surface by the Earth's tidal field.

Not only objects could be pulled from surface, but the planet's surface could also be pulled)))

That's exactly it. The Roche limit article says "Objects resting on the surface of such a satellite would be lifted away by tidal forces". Thanks.
